# Proposition infinitive en tant que sujet et conjugaison

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, subjonctif, conditionnel

Je viens de lire un texte qui m'a surpris :

> Vous avez écrit "[...]". Écrire "[...]" eût été préférable.

Je pensais que c'était une faute (du subjonctif imparfait avec du présent), mais il semblerait qu'en fait le subjonctif imparfait peut se substituer au conditionnel passé dans un langage soutenu. Est-ce bien correct dans ce cas-ci ? De plus, je n'ai rien trouvé sur Internet concernant l'utilisation du conditionnel passé avec une subordonnée infinitive en tant que sujet, ce qui me fait douter de tout maintenant.

Éclairez-moi, je suis perplexe...

Comment: Le sujet est induit, dans la formulation moins soutenue : "Il eût été préférable d'*écrire* [...]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"eût été" est le plus-que-parfait du subjonctif de "être".

En langage soutenu, il peut parfaitement remplacer le conditionnel "aurait".

---

Autre chose : vous écrivez "... il semblerait  ...peut se substituer ..." ; utiliser l'indicatif "peut" après le conditionnel "semblerait" est illogique, puisqu'il y a doute.

Le conditionnel dans la principale entraîne l'imparfait du subjonctif dans la subordonnée. Il eût fallu écrire ".....pût se substituer ..."

Comment: Heu, oui exact, du plus-que-parfait du subjonctif. Petite faute de ma part. Merci d'avoir relevé mon erreur, il faut effectivement employer du subjonctif après "il semblerait" ; mais je pense qu'on peut aussi utiliser le présent (du subjonctif) : "...puisse se substituer...". Enfin, existe-t-il une règle quant au temps à utiliser après une subordonnée infinitive sujet ? Je constate qu'on peut utiliser du conditionnel passé, mais aussi du futur antérieur ("Avoir un enfant aura été ma plus belle réussite") voire du présent.

Comment: Selon la règle classique : "doute au présent de l'indicatif dans la principale implique présent du subjonctif dans la subordonnée" ; "doute au présent du conditionnel dans la principale implique imparfaitdu subjonctif dans la subordonnée". "Il semble qu'il puisse se substituer ...". Une proposition infinitive sujet est intemporelle : Avoir un enfant fut / est / sera / aurait été / eut été ... , tout est possible.

Answer (score 3):

Ici, « eût été » n'est pas un plus-que-parfait du subjonctif, mais un « conditionnel passé deuxième forme ». En tout cas, c'est comme cela que les grammaires que j'ai pu rencontrer le décrivent. Il n'y a aucune de différence de sens entre le conditionnel passé première forme (la forme habituelle : « aurait été ») et la deuxième forme. La deuxième forme est soutenue, voire quelque peu désuette.

On peut tout à fait utiliser une proposition dont le verbe est à l'infinitif comme sujet ou comme complément d'un autre verbe.

> Écrire « … » est préférable.
>   Écrire « … » serait préférable.
>   Écrire « … » aurait été préférable.
>   Écrire « … » eût été préférable.
>   Il est (serait, aurait été, eût été, …) préférable d'écrire « … ».
>   Je préfère écrire « … ».
>   J'ai regretté avoir écrit « … ».